# JSON: php to javascript data conversion gives me an error on eval

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

Hi im fairly new to using JSON and have been trying to pass an array from PHP to Javascript using JSON. I have been reading up a bit on it but am having an error on the eval function in javascripts side of the code. If anyone couid please help id really appreciate it thanks in advance!

**PHP (lang.en.php)**

```
<?php
$lang['TITLE'] = 'My Title';
$lang['MESSAGE'] = 'My Message';
?>
```

**HTML/Javascript (index.php)**

```
<?php
include "lang/lang.en.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
    //Get the JSON string and pass it to the cb function
    $.get("index.php", function(data){cb(data)});
})

function cb(data){
    //converts the JSON string to a JavaScript object
    eval("lang="+data); //This is where the error occurs
    lang = dataToObj;
    alert(lang.TITLE);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<? json_encode($lang); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. What does `data` contain?

Comment: Soo, what's that supposed to do? Where is the JSON string? If I read this right, you are getting the HTML *again* and `eval`ing it.

Comment: jQuery converts it to an object for you already. `data` should be a javascript object, try just using it like one.

Comment: @Pekka if i alert(data) its returning all the code on the page...

Comment: What @Niklas says is correct. The JSON data needs to stand on its own, you mustn't wrap it in HTML. You're probably best off putting the JSON call into a separate script file that you call

Comment: @Niklas B I want to be able to read my php variables in javascript so when the user interacts with an item on my page it knows what language to display the text that changes upon interaction... (Of course this isnt the code to my real page i made a dummy page to test how JSON works before implementing it, since im new to it...)

Comment: @Pekka This will all be in a seperate file eventually, but i need it to work first as this is just dummy code i am using to see how it works exactly...

Comment: @Chad the issue is when i check what data contains it has the code for index.php in it i dont see the array... if i put echo in front of json_encode($lang); it shows me the array meaning that the data its encoding is correct...